# Java - issue with memory

Tags: java, heap-memory, jvm-arguments

Need some help from the experts!

We have a project here (still on dev) that needs to run 50 java processes (for now and it will probably doubled or tripled in the future) at the same time every 5 minutes. I set Xmx50m for every process and our server has only 4gb of RAM, I know that would really slow our server. What I have in mind is to upgrade our RAM. My question is that do I have other options to prevent our server from being slow when running that amount of java processes?

Comment: Your problem is your system design which uses Java for "lightweight" processes. JVM process is heavyweight and the usual design is to have many tasks within the same process.

Comment: so do you suggest that I really need to upgrade our RAM?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 50 process and as per your assumption your processes need about 2.5 Gb to run .
To prevent your server from being slow you can follow some [best practices](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078731/java-platform/jvm-performance-optimization--part-5--is-java-scalability-an-oxymoron-.html) to set java memory parameters e.g. set -Xmin and -Xmx the same values and determine a proper values based on your process usage, Also you can [profile your process](https://visualvm.java.net/gettingstarted.html) on runtime to ensure that everything is ok.